# Do something to selected image in scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I try to make following: Horizontal list of images, that I can select and do something with it. For example flip image around x axis. I know how to rotate image. I created scrollview and load it with images. I added event handler when I tap on image. But I don't know how to do something with tapped image. How to code method to do something with tapped image?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];        

    img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgTest.jpg"];
    img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgTest2.jpg"];

    arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img1];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img2];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img1];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img2];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 128);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UIImage *imageToAdd;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for(imageToAdd in arrayOfImages)
    {
        UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToAdd];     

        temp.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 128, 128);
        temp.userInteractionEnabled = YES;      
        x += 135;


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
        [temp addGestureRecognizer:tap];    

        [scrollView addSubview:temp];
    }
...

- (void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    // how to get reference on selected item in scrollview???   
}
```

Comment: There are some memory-leaks in your code. You have to release those UIImageViews and UITapGestureRecognizers, you create.

Comment: 1110, I added the gesture recognizer like you have done but have been unable to get the imageTapped event handler to get called. Did you have to update the code above to get it working? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A gesture recognizer has a `view` property that returns the view associated with the recognizer. Since you know that it'll be a UIImageView you can simply cast it and use it as in:

```
UIImageView *iv = (UIImageView *)[sender view];
```

And your image can then be queried via:

```
UIImage *image = [iv image];
```

If you need to know the index in your array, there are two ways: either simply use `[arrayOfImages indexOfObject:image];`, or you can assign tags (numbers) to views and use them. A tag is not used by Apple, it's only here so we developers can "mark" views in some way. For example:

```
NSInteger counter = 0;
for(imageToAdd in arrayOfImages)
{
    UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToAdd];
    count.tag = counter++;
    ...
}
```

Then, in your `imageTapped:`, you can query the index via `tag`:

```
NSInteger index = [imageView tag];
```